# angular-timer with webpack

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, angular-timer

I tried using angular-timer with webpack, es6 and the npm modules of [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) and [humanize-duration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/humanize-duration)

My implementation would be:

```
import 'moment';
import 'humanize-duration';
import 'angular-timer';
```

And I get the error `ReferenceError: humanizeDuration is not defined`.

Sure, angular-timer needs the variable humanizeDuration and suggests in the [requirements section](https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer#requirements) to use bower and *script src*. In my understanding importing the src with webpack is the same as using it as src in a script tag.

Comment: How have you installed these libraries?  Via npm? (npm is preferred)

Comment: Hi, @Yves can you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

This help for me:

1. Install moment and humanize-duration:

   `$ npm install moment`

   `$ npm install humanize-duration`
2. Install them in your webpack.config.js as plugins:

```js
module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig() {
    /**
     * Config
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html
     * This is the object where all configuration gets set
     */
    var config = {};
    
  config.plugins = [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 'moment': 'moment',   'humanizeDuration': 'humanize-duration' })
    ];
```

3. And import angular-timer in your component

```js
import 'angular';
import 'angular-timer';

let yourModule = angular.module('your', [
    'timer'
]);
```

I hope this will help you